# Not able to setup variable value in the output console of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, console, vscode-snippets

I am coding in Python and recently I have been facing this issue in which I am not able to set the variable value in the output console of VS Code. In the output console, it will show that the code is running but if I try to type to put in the values of the variable, the console won't work. I am not able to type the values.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing VS Code, but it didn't work. I am still facing the same issue. I tried removing unnecessary extensions also.

Comment: the terminal is not a REPL, what is the **prompt** you see in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You might need to post your code so we can see the full issue. Despite that, I'll say that you can't change variables in a script during runtime through the console unless you set up a specific call for them, such as using `x = input(x)`.

If you're wanting to test values of variables during execution you can use the Python debugger included in the basic Python extension in VS Code. Just set a breakpoint (toggle the red dot to the left of the line you want to pause at), run the program, then when the execution pauses go to the **Debug Console** tab in the console. This allows for dynamic updating of program variables using normal Python expression.